# mysql views at runtime vs creating tables at runtime : performance and other issues

Tags: php, mysql, performance

I am working on a GPS application, where more that 5000 devices are going to send data to the server every 2 minutes.

The system is being developed in cakephp 2.0 and Mysql

Keeping the speed of application in mind, i am trying to create 3 tables at runtime during the company registration like

```
companyid_today - stores the records for all devices of the company for today
companyid_yesterday - stores all the records for all devoices of the company for yesterday 
companyid_history - stores all the records - for history search.
```

I clear the today and yesterday tables by crons at the end the day and copy the today data to yesterday.

This is done to make the rendering on maps faster as quering on very large tables and rendering on maps takes a huge amount of time

I have other options in mind like

creating views at the runtime based on the company id during the company registration but need to know the support of views for mysql 5.5.31 and if views can be created based on the logic of current dates.

Need advice on the best approach keeping the speed of the application and large number of data handling in mind

Comment: If your primary concern is keeping it from searching the entire database for "today's" records, just make the date an indexed field. When you declare the date, it will quickly ignore everything not on that date's index. If, however, you really really want all data on a date to be stuck together, partition on the date. Internally, you will get a cluster of records for each date. No work on your end. Of course, renaming "today" to "yesterday" is a trivial exercise. I would just prefer to avoid it by keeping it all in one indexed/partitioned table.

Comment: If by creating tables or views at runtime you mean your PHP application will do a SQL query `create table ...` or `create view ...`, then please don't. If that's not what you mean, don't call it creating views or tables at runtime.

Comment: @kainaw that means if i index based on date and vehicle id i should be getting the same performance even if there are ate more than 10000000 records on table and will not hamper and performance.

Comment: @developerwjk yes i mean creating views and table at runtime from the application so that all data of a company are logically at one place and the application weirdos the table or view instead of the large table.

Comment: @kainaw i am storing the date as a timestamp value and companyid as bigint unsigned. What is the best way to create the partition, if i want to keep data of company id and timestamp field stuck together for best results. I already have an index placed, any other better ideas

Comment: @user2055396 I work with over 10 million records incoming daily. I run on-demand reports that hit the entire database (multi-billions of rows). In a worst-case scenario, it takes about 2 minutes to get a report out. It is all about indexing and partitioning. The big issue is to ensure that your indexes are actually used. Then, inserting data is where the overhead takes place. Extracting is very fast. Note: I actually use MariaDB, not MySQL. However, it is very similar.

Comment: @kainaw I have created index of company_id and date(timestamp field). What type of partitioning do you suggest?